# Iterating through a linked list

Tags: java, linked-list, listiterator

I have made a LinkedList that has a LinkedListIterator that implements the interface `Iterator<E>`.

The Interface has these functions:

```
Next();
hasNext();
```

I am trying to iterate through my LinkedList using an iterator function that returns an `Iterator<E>` object. This is my function:

```
public Iterator<E> iterator(int stop) {

    if(size==0){
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("IMPLEMENT THIS METHOD");
    }
    Iterator<E> result = new LinkedListIterator();
    for(int i = 0; i<stop; i++){
        result.next();
    }
    return result;
}
```

I also have a test class that runs through a simulation of the Iterator:

```
public class TestLinkedList {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        //StudentInfo.display();

        LinkedList<Integer> xs;
        final int MAX_SIZE = 5;

        for (int stop = 0; stop<MAX_SIZE; stop++) {
            for (int start = 0; start<=stop; start++) {

                System.out.println("start="+start+", stop="+stop);

                xs = new LinkedList<Integer>();

                for (int i=0; i<MAX_SIZE; i++) {
                    xs.addLast(i);
                }

                System.out.println(xs);

                Iterator<Integer> i = xs.iterator(stop);

                while (i.hasNext()) {
                    System.out.println(i.next());
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is my other implemenation of iterator:

```
public Iterator<E> iterator(int start, int stop) {
    if(size == 0){
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("IMPLEMENT THIS METHOD");
    }

    Iterator<E> result = new LinkedListIterator();
    for(int i = start; i<stop; i++){
        result.next();
    }
    return result;
}
```

When I run the simulation I get a result of:

```
start=0, stop=0
{0,1,2,3,4}
0
1
2
3
4
start=0, stop=1
{0,1,2,3,4}
1
2
3
4
start=1, stop=1
{0,1,2,3,4}
1
2
3
4
start=0, stop=2
{0,1,2,3,4}
2
3
4
start=1, stop=2
{0,1,2,3,4}
2
3
4
start=2, stop=2
{0,1,2,3,4}
2
3
4
start=0, stop=3
{0,1,2,3,4}
3
4
start=1, stop=3
{0,1,2,3,4}
3
4
start=2, stop=3
{0,1,2,3,4}
3
4
start=3, stop=3
{0,1,2,3,4}
3
4
start=0, stop=4
{0,1,2,3,4}
4
start=1, stop=4
{0,1,2,3,4}
4
start=2, stop=4
{0,1,2,3,4}
4
start=3, stop=4
{0,1,2,3,4}
4
start=4, stop=4
{0,1,2,3,4}
4
```

When I should get a result of:

```
// start=0, stop=0
// {0,1,2,3,4}
// 0
// start=0, stop=1
// {0,1,2,3,4}
// 0
// 1
// start=1, stop=1
// {0,1,2,3,4}
// 1
// start=0, stop=2
// {0,1,2,3,4}
// 0
// 1
// 2
// start=1, stop=2
// {0,1,2,3,4}
// 1
// 2
// start=2, stop=2
// {0,1,2,3,4}
// 2
// start=0, stop=3
// {0,1,2,3,4}
// 0
// 1
// 2
// 3
// start=1, stop=3
// {0,1,2,3,4}
// 1
// 2
// 3
// start=2, stop=3
// {0,1,2,3,4}
// 2
// 3
// start=3, stop=3
// {0,1,2,3,4}
// 3
// start=0, stop=4
// {0,1,2,3,4}
// 0
// 1
// 2
// 3
// 4
// start=1, stop=4
// {0,1,2,3,4}
// 1
// 2
// 3
// 4
// start=2, stop=4
// {0,1,2,3,4}
// 2
// 3
// 4
// start=3, stop=4
// {0,1,2,3,4}
// 3
// 4
// start=4, stop=4
// {0,1,2,3,4}
// 4
```

I do not understand what I am missing in my Iterator function can someone please help me with this?

Comment: Hint: you're not using `start`

Comment: @VivekChavda the function only runs on the variable stop which is what I want. This was an assignment given by a teacher. He wants me to implement Iterator with a stop parameter first. Using the test that he wrote himself

Comment: See I have two implementations of Iterator @VivekChavda one with start and one with start, stop

Comment: Ah, thanks, I misunderstood. I can see the issue here, your stop function is basically a start function. I'd post the code you wrote and can modify

Comment: If you can help me out that would be great thank you so much I just need help with the stop function i can do the start-stop on my own

Comment: if you can do the "start-stop" function the "stop" function only has to call the "star-stop" function with start=0

Comment: I'm having trouble with both though. I don't understand what I am doing wrong with my for loop

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your iterator is being improperly generated. You are first generating the iterator and then using `.next()` to remove `stop` number of elements from the front and then returning an iterator that will run though the remainder of the list until the then end when `hasNext()` returns false. Your method should read something like that.

```
public Iterator<E> iterator(int start) {
    if(size == 0){
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("IMPLEMENT THIS METHOD");
    }
    Iterator<E> result = new LinkedListIterator();
    for(int i = 0; i<start; i++){
        result.next();
    }
    return result;
}
```

In order to implement the stop value. I imagine you would have to change the implementation of LinkedListIterator to allow a property to cause `hasNext()` to return false `stop` number of elements before the end.